# get text out of table in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have tried to read text out of a table column that is in an iframe . 
I'm not sure if it is possible. But this is what I tried so far:

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").document.getElementsByClassName("columnclass")[12].textContent();
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("iframeid").getElementsByClassName`

Comment: thanks ... but I get the same error again